# need to hide attributes if attribute value is " "

Tags: attributes

http://pastebin.com/6uzYgauE

we are using above attributes.phtml file to display the attibutes in frontend.

app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

suppose if attribute value is empty , than thiose attributes will not display in frontend for the

particular product .

but if we give some empty space in the attribute text field, than those attributes are displaying in the frontend.

if we gave empty space as attribute values , than we want to hide those attributes for the particular product.

ex: if attribute manufacturer = "" than color will not display in frontend

if attribute manufacturer = " " than color will display in frontend. we want to hide color here....

please help me to find solution.

Comment: You could use trim() to eliminate the whitespace. Or use if(empty($yourvar))

Comment: can you please infrom in detail, in which line i have to do which chnages....

Comment: presumably this bit: ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != ''))

Comment: can you please give complete code and please inform me after which line ,i have to place the above code.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you could replace the line 49 with something like `if(strlen(trim($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())))>0 && strlen(trim(((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) > 0)))`

Comment: i tried this : syntax error, unexpected '<' in line 50

Comment: ok, so make sure there are the right number of opening and closing brackets (both in that if statement and for php). For example my comment missed the `{ ?>` at the end. Just make sure the if statement and the php parts have the same opening and closing brackets

Comment: please post your commnet as answer, its worked for med : if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && (trim((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) != '')) { ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace line 49

```
if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
```

With

```
if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && (trim((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) != '')) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**from :**

```
<?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
```

**with**

```
<?php $yourAtttrbute = $_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode()); 
$yourAtttrbute2 = $_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$desLen = strlen(trim($yourAtttrbute));
$desLen2 = strlen(trim($yourAtttrbute2));
     if($desLen != 0 && $desLen2 != 0)
 {
    ?>
```

Comment: can you please inform in detail, in which line i have to do which changes.... i s i have to manually fro all attribute codes ?

Comment: change code on line no 48

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$desLen' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/2/app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml on line 50

please check : http://pastebin.com/QfeQ1f7r

Comment: i have edited ans plz check it i was forget (;)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object onl ine 49 in http://pastebin.com/KnC3mCyM

Answer (score 1):

Find attribute.phtml in this code

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
     <tr>
         <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
         <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
     </tr>
```

Replace to this

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
   <?php if ((string)$_data['value'] != '' and $_data['value'] != 'N/A'): ?>
   <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /var/www/html/demo4/app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml on line 68 = >http://pastebin.com/tSS8RPR3

Comment: delete one endif

Comment: its not working..... http://pastebin.com/0DZ0hzwt

Comment: @BabyinMagento without string not wokring, may i know what is the reason? don't need to give data type in PHP right?